# Replacing specific characters in between substrings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, substring

I have a string of HTML with handlebars like the following:

```
var text = '<p>This is the {{description}}</p><pre><code class="hljs">{{capitalize property}}</code></pre>'
```

I would like to search through the string and replace the handlebars brackets (i.e. `{` and `}`) with another character (in this case, a string that represents the html entity. For example, `&#123;` and `&#125;`, respectively) only when the handlebars are between opening and closing code tags (note, the tags can have a class).

Thus, the above string would look like this:

```
var text = '<p>This is the {{description}}</p><pre><code class="hljs">&#123;&#123;capitalize property&#125;&#125;</code></pre>'
```

**Possible Options:**

I understand I could append the string to the document and manipulate it with jQuery. I am also aware of the `DOMparser()` method.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I am trying, in Javascript? And would that method have major performance disadvantages?

My attempts have looked something like this:

```
string.replace(/<code[^>]*>({)<\/code>/g, '&#123;');
```

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions to parse HTML code can be really slow or result unexpected consequences.

Anyhow, this code tries to locate all `<code>` blocks and replaces `{{` and `}}` with `[[` and `]]`. Code block can have multiple attributes.

```
text.replace(/<code(?:\s+[^>]+)*>(?:.*?{{.+?}})*.*<\/code>/g, function(a) {
    return(a.replace(/{{/g, "[[").replace(/}}/g, "]]"));
})
```